# Angular 5 send @Input down a set of components

Tags: angular, angular5

In component 1 I do something like this:

```
<app-child-one [foo]="foo">
```

And I'm able to then use the value just fine in `ngOnInit`.  But in child one's HTML it then wants to use that as well to pass again:

```
<app-grandchild [foo]="foo">
```

Because the `app-grandchild` is set up before `foo` is actually bound, the controller gets a `null` value.  How do I do this the right way so that the bound value is passed all the way through?

Comment: @Deshak9 Yes it's an Input.  The trick was using it with a setter vs. just the direct input, as bryan60 showed in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a setter Input instead of trying to access onInit

like so:

```
@Input()
set foo(value) {
   //do whatever with value that you would do onInit
}
```

Now the setter will run everytime the input value changes rather than just looking at it onInit

If you also need to get foo, then you just add a getter as well and can use a local variable for storage

```
private _foo;
@Input()
set foo(value) {
   this._foo = value;
   //do whatever with value that you would do onInit
}
get foo() {
   return this._foo;
}
```

It looks a little verbose but lets you handle the case where your input variable may be set sometime after init and you need to do something else with the value.  Other choices here are to use later lifecycle hooks (afterviewinit?) or use a shared service instead of inputs.  I wouldnt recommend trying to use later lifecycle hooks, it might be the quickest fix right now, but it makes your component have a hidden timing dependency that could change later and break your component in an unexpected way.